# AIR4: How to restore audio in iOS 8 (beta 5) after requesting mic access?

Tags: ios, air, ios8, microphone

**Problem:** iOS 8 (beta 5) fades out all sound output in my app after listening for sample data, and never restores it, but only if sound has been played before requesting microphone sample data.

[Another user noted that this behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21144381/air-mobile-microphone-on-iphone-4-mute-all-sounds) stems from requesting microphone access, but sound plays as expected in our released app using iOS7 in both of the cases below, and the workaround to close/reopen the app isn't a viable solution since microphone recording is an recurring part of our app.

**Conditions:**

- Flex 4.6.0 & AIR 4.0
- iPad 3 (MD335LL/A)
- iOS 8 (12A4345D)
- Both test cases assume that microphone permission has been granted..

**Test case 0:**

- Play sound
- Stop sound channel
- Audio stops
- Connect to microphone, remove listener once sample data received
- Attempt to play sound
- No audible output, nor does the sound complete event ever fire

**Test case 1:**

- Connect to microphone, remove listener once sample data received
- Sounds plays without a problem and sound complete event is fired

**Sample code:**

```
    protected var _url:String = 'audio/organfinale.mp3';
    protected var _sound:Sound;
    protected var _soundChannel:SoundChannel;
    protected var _microphone:Microphone;

    public function init():void
    {
        initSound();
    }


    /** SOUND **/

    protected function initSound():void
    {
        // Set up to mimic app
        SoundMixer.audioPlaybackMode = AudioPlaybackMode.MEDIA;

        _sound = new Sound( new URLRequest( _url ) );
        _sound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSoundLoaded );
    }

    protected function onSoundLoaded(e:Event):void
    {
        _sound.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSoundLoaded);

        switch ( 0 )
        {
            // Will cut audio completely, prevent audio dispatch
            case 0:
                playSound();
                setTimeout( initMicrophone, 1500 );
                break;

            // Works perfectly (because no overlap between sound/microphone?)
            case 1:
                initMicrophone();
                break;
        }
    }

    protected function playSound():void
    {
        trace( 'Play sound' );

        if ( _soundChannel && _soundChannel.hasEventListener( Event.SOUND_COMPLETE ) )
                _soundChannel.removeEventListener( Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onSoundCompleted );

        _soundChannel = _sound.play( 0 );
        _soundChannel.addEventListener( Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onSoundCompleted, false, 0, true );
    }

    protected function onSoundCompleted( e:Event ):void
    {
        trace( "Sound complete" );
    }


    /** MICROPHONE **/

    protected function initMicrophone():void
    {
        if ( Microphone.isSupported )
        {
            // Testing pre-emptive disposal of sound that might be conflicting with microphone in iOS 8
            if ( _soundChannel )
            {
                // Tested this, but it throws an error because sound is not streaming
                // _sound.close();

                _soundChannel.removeEventListener( Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onSoundCompleted );
                _soundChannel.stop();
                _soundChannel = null;

                // Instead the sound will be cut abruptedly, and will fail to dispatch complete event
            }

            _microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();
            _microphone.setSilenceLevel(0);
            // _microphone.setUseEchoSuppression(true);
            // _microphone.gain = 50;
            // _microphone.rate = 44;
            _microphone.addEventListener( SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, onSampleDataReceived, false, 0, true );
        }
        else
        {
            trace( 'Microphone is not supported!' );
        }
    }

    protected function onSampleDataReceived( e:SampleDataEvent ):void
    {
        trace( 'Sample data received' );

        _microphone.removeEventListener( SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, onSampleDataReceived );
        _microphone = null;

        setTimeout( playSound, 1500 );
    }
```

Notes:

- I stopped the sound channel before adding the mic listener, assuming that might have been causing a conflict, but it made no difference.
- I've tested using the same device/OS after compiling the app with Flex 4.6.0 & AIR 14.0, and the problem persists.
- By comparison, testing this app on iOS 7 worked in both cases.

Any ideas?

**Update 1:** Bug has been logged here: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3801262

**Update 2:** Bug is fixed as of AIR 15.0.0.274: http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/air.html